# Can not install cocoapods because of the password on Mac desktop

Tags: operating-system, passwords, cocoapods, sudo

I have been trying to install using the command `sudo gem install cocoapods`  on my desktop with OS. X  High Sierra. After entering the command, it asks for the password. I enter an administrator password and it replies "Sorry, try again". Also, by the password, I see a sign of a key. Does it mean it is somehow locked? I wonder what could be the problem? I appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem ?.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem, the logged in user has no password so when it asks for the password I just press enter and the problem happened.
and the solution in my case was just to add a password to the logged in user and use it

Answer (score 1):

The "password" requested is the MacOS (Macbook/iMac) password you use to unlock your Mac.  Cocoapods OUGHT to specify this in terminal's verbiage.

To get a password (if you don't have one), follow the instructions in the picture below...[image]